# Change the DirectoryIndex based on a domain/sub-domain in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directoryindex

I have a shared hosting with one domain and one sub-domain (for mobile and clients). Each domain and sub-domains has different default index pages. The hosting company told me to put everything in my .htaccess file since I don't have access to the httpd.conf.

What I want to do is this:

1. If a user goes to domain1.com the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `index.html`
2. If a user goes to mobile.domain1.com the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `mobile-index.html`
3. If a user goes to post.domain1.com the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `post.php`
4. If a user goes to vote.domain1.com the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `vote.php`

Edit:
In addition, if I go to domain1.com/page/ the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `index.html`. If I go to mobile.domain1.com/page/ the `DirectoryIndex` should be: `mobile-index.html`

What can I put in my .htaccess file in order to change the `DirectoryIndex` for each sub-domain?

Thank You very mich

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<IfDefine>` does not work like that. `<IfDefine>` only runs when apache starts. You should go with a mod_rewrite solution. view @tzakrajs answer.

You can use this in your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^www\. page=www
SetEnvIf Host ^mobile\. page=mobile
rewriterule ^.*$ test.php?subdomain=%{ENV:page} [QSA,L]
```

Simply just configure all your sub-domain using `SetEnvIf` and then simply let the PHP do its magic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Thanks for the SetEnvIf, I think that is way easier to implement (instead of creating 4 different files). Thanks

Comment: In other words: `<IfDefine>` is not dynamic after Apache starts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/$ index.html [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/$ mobile-index.html [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^post.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/$ post.php [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vote.domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^.*/$ vote.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: thanks that works for the landing page, but it does not work for Sub Folder. for example mobile.domain1.com/page/ should load the mobile-index.html

Comment: Alright, I have modified the rules so that they will match any subdirectory (ex: domain1.com/fdskjfkls/ will redirect to index.html)

Comment: It does but does not redirect to: domain1.com/fdskjfkls/index.html and mobile.domain1.com/fdskjfkls/mobile.html

Answer (score -1):

You can set using just oyur `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule DirectoryIndex mobile-index.html

...
```

Comment: @laxman you don't need to down vote just because it didn't work for you